# Am getting this error. MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [remove] on [shoeDatabase.users]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, meanjs

This error is what I find. user is not allowed to do action
`MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [remove] on [shoeDatabase.users],`

```
import express from "express";
import User from "./Models/UserModel.js";
import users from "./data/users.js";
const ImportData = express.Router();

ImportData.post("/user", async (req, res) => {
  await User.remove({});
  const importUser = await User.insertMany(users);
  res.send({ importUser });
});

export default ImportData;
```

Answer (score 0):

solution for your error is :

- change the rights in the database
- your script has not rights to remove any `user`

there are other problems to address:

- `await User.remove({});` will remove all present users... are you sure?
- where are `users` originated from? (should be parsed from req and are not)